# OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not visible c# selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium

I'm trying to click on a radio button and the only problem is that I keep getting the error 'element not visible'. I have looked at similar problems on this site and have tried several things, but none of them seem to work. How do I make the element visible so that I can click on it?

When the code reaches 'allships.Click();' the error occurs. My page object class:

```
public class MatchShipmentsToLocationsPage
    {
        //instance of the IWebDriver interface
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        //fields that are used to find the needed HTML elements for our tests to pass
        private By lineItemTableLocator = By.Id("lineItemTable");
        private By locationSearchInputBoxLocator = By.Id("locationSearch");
        private By groupSearchLocationSearchLocator = By.CssSelector(".input-group.search.location-search");

        private By applyLocationForLocator = By.Id("applyLocation");

        private By justThisInvoiceRadioButtonLocator = By.Id("rbThisInvoice");

        //constructor, constructs the the page
        public MatchShipmentsToLocationsPage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this._driver = driver;
        }

public MatchShipmentsToLocationsPage selectAllFutureShipmentsRadioButton()
        {

            var applyOptions = _driver.FindElement(applyLocationForLocator);

            var allships = applyOptions.FindElements(By.Name("locationGroup"))[1];

            allships.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return this;
        }

    }
```

The Html:

```
<div id="applyLocation" class="panel-subsection">
                    <div class="panel-subsection-header">Allow for</div>
                    <div class="radio-button-section">
                        <div class="container radiocontainer">
::before
                            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="locationGroup" id="rbThisInvoice">
                            <label for="rbThisInvoice">
                                <span class="radio inline radio-span radio-label">Just this invoice</span>
                            </label>
::after
                        </div>

                        <div class="container radiocontainer">
::before
                            <input type="radio" name="locationGroup" id="rbAllShipments">
                            <label for="rbAllShipments">
                                <span class="radio inline radio-span radio-label">
             ::before
              All Future Shipments</span>
                            </label>
             ::after
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: If you figured out a solution, post it as an answer and accept it so the question gets marked as solved.

Comment: Thanks, just did that @JeffC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :) I clicked the element via javascript:

```
public MatchShipmentsToLocationsPage selectJustThisInvoiceRadioButton()
        {

            var applyOptions = _driver.FindElement(applyLocationForLocator);
            //var justThisInvoiceRadioButton = applyOptions.FindElement(By.Id())
            //_driver.FindElement(justThisInvoiceRadioButtonLocator).Click();

            //var allFutureShipmentsRadioButtonLocator = applyOptions.FindElement(By.Id("rbAllShipments"));
            //allFutureShipmentsRadioButtonLocator.Click();

            var allships = applyOptions.FindElements(By.Name("locationGroup"))[1];

            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", allships);


          //  allships.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return this;
        }
```